# Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection (looking for another solution)

Tags: r, file

I've been looking for solutions but I still can't fix it.

If you have any idea ?

My current directory is : "C:/Users/François/Desktop/CHALLENGE KAGGLE/données/google"

Here you can find my code :

```
            setwd("C:/Users/François/Desktop/CHALLENGE KAGGLE/données/google")
getwd ()

files_names <- list.files(path="C:/Users/François/Desktop/CHALLENGE KAGGLE/données/google")
nb_files <- length(files_names)
data_names <- vector("list",length=nb_files)

for (i in 1 : nb_files)
{
  data_names[i] <- strsplit(files_names[i], split=".csv")
}

for (i in 1:nb_files) {
  assign(data_names[[i]],
         read.csv2(paste (here("/", files_names[i])),sep=",",skip=1))
}
```

and the error message is : Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

I get this error after the last loop. The first one works well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing a `for` loop, an option is `lapply` and store the output in a `list`

```
lst1 <- lapply(file_names, read.csv, skip = 1)
names(lst1) <- sub("\\.csv", "", file_names)
```

It is better not to create multiple objects in the global environment with `assign`.  If it is really needed

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

In the OP's code, the assignment to 'data_names' can be

```
data_names[[i]] <- strsplit(files_names[i], split=".csv", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
```

as `data_names` is initialized as a `list`.  By doing the `data_names[i]`, it is creating a list element inside the list.  Also, the output of `strsplit` is a `list`.  Here, we split each 'files_names' separately, so it would be a `list` of length 1.  We need to extract that element as a vector (`[[1]]`)